# Space Over Image in IE (table-based layout email layout)

Tags: html, html-email

I am designing an html email campaign, and per the advice of MailChimp and this article:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/code-html-email-newsletters

I am using tables (gasp!) to do my layout.

You can see the spacing problem I have if you visit the following page in both IE and firefox:

http://test888.moochomoocho.com/

There is a space in IE only between the gutter images and the header.  I can't figure out what's causing it or how to get rid of it.

Thanks for any help,
Jonah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the whitespace before and after the image..

make

```
<td colspan="3" width="600" height="174">
    <img src="images/header.png">
</td>
```

to

```
<td colspan="3" width="600" height="174"><img src="images/header.png"></td>
```

Comment: wow, IE -- never ceases to amaze.  Thank you so much for solving that!